# Input/output resistance for an accelerometer/Wheatstone bridge

Tags: output, accelerometer, input-impedance, wheatstone-bridge, bridge

I am looking at the [MS 3028 Piezoresistive Accelerometer](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Data%20Sheet%7F3028_Accelerometer%7FA1%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_DS_3028_Accelerometer_A1.pdf%7FCAT-EAC0002).

This is the internal schematic of the component, as a Wheatstone bridge, which per my understanding means it's a quarter bridge with other elements being piezoresistive elements that are not actively used for sensing, and are used mainly for temperature compensation.

[image]

[image]

I looked into other SE posts such as [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/423846/what-does-input-output-resistance-impedance-mean) or [that one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/213273/input-resistance-vs-output-resistance). Per my understanding, input resistance is the resistance between the +ve and -ve supply, in this case between terminal 2 and 3, or terminal 1 and 3. Output resistance is the resistance between the +ve and -ve element of the load and assuming zero impedance between supply +ve and -ve, and I am confused by where output resistance goes.

In this case, is the output resistance simply total resistance between terminal 4 and 5, given that 3 is assumed to be shorted with 1 and 2? It doesn't help that one of the resistive elements is expected to vary significantly. Please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: By Input and Output, the manufacturer means terminals 3-4, 3-5, 2-5, 1-5. The resistors all have the same value and can vary between 2500_Ohm and 6500_Ohm.

Comment: Thank you. So input is 3-4 and 3-5, and output is 2-5 and 1-5? Can you expand this into an answer and elaborate so I can mark this as solved?

Answer (score 1):

Wheatstone bridge power supply: positive to terminal 3, negative to 1 and 2; outputs 4-5. The sensor should be used as shown:

[image]

Comment: Can you label the points to be used in calculating input and output resistance? I know that in input and output resistance are just different versions equivalent resistance with different "start" and "end" points, but would be nice to have them indicated.

Answer (score 0):

For me, input and output resistance means the dynamic resistances between the terminals. To get a sure answer on what is meant by input and output resistance provided by the sensor data sheet, you should ask the manufacturer directly:

[image]